# Vuejs - Find unused props. events and components

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vuejs SPA that I want to clean-up and do some refactoring on. One thing I would like to do is detect

- Unused or extra `props` defined in custom components. I don't mean within the component itself (this I do via `eslint-plugin-vue`), but when the component is instantiated somewhere in the app within another component.
- Unused or extra `$emits` defined in custom components. Again, are there `$emit` that are never actually handled when instantiating a component?
- Identify component's `data` that actually dont need to be reactive and can be removed from `data`
- Unused components
- Unused `exports` in my `js` files

The linter I use, `eslint-plugin-vue`, does its work component by component but here I want to be checking unused stuff across several components.

I could not find any built-in tool for these tasks, what's the best way to do this?

Even if the app contains hundreds of components I could still do this manually, but ideally I would like to run this process frequently to keep the app clean.